# Object created via spread operator weird behaviour

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue.js a spread operator in order to create a new array and find a value inside of it that will be assigned to `selectedEmployee` data property:

```
selectEmployee(id) {
  const employees = [...this.employees];
  this.selectedEmployee = employees.find(employee => employee.id === id);
},
```

Either way, modifying the `selectedEmployee` value through `v-model` also modifies the record saved at the `paginatedEmployees` property which is beign defined like this:

```
async fetchEmployees() {
  this.loading = true;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/employees');
    this.employees = response.data.employees;
    this.paginatedEmployees = _.chunk(this.employees, 10);
    this.pages = this.paginatedEmployees.length;
  } catch (e) {
    this.error = true;
    this.requestMessage = e.message;
  } finally {
    this.loading = false;
  }
},
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreading makes a shallow copy which means you have a new array of the *same* employees.

You would want to make a copy of your selected employee instead so you don’t mutate the original employee.

Keep in mind this would also be a shallow copy so if your employee has nested objects, those will still reference the originals just like in your array scenario. This is what makes spreading such a cheap operation versus a *deep* copy/clone.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've ended up using lodash cloneDeep function and now it works just fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that deep cloning is an expensive operation and best to avoid if you can. For example do you need to change the employee prop in your component? Or can you create a computer prop instead? If you can avoid mutating existing objects you can save a lot of pains that come with it.

Comment: An alternative to consider is https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutability-helper; it has a small learning curve for the syntax but is very effective. You tell it what you want to update and it does the minimum number of shallow clones necessary to avoid mutation. This also very helpful for situations like React/Redux where object identity is used to know what things haven't changed.